# Lookup Combo that supports remote data - load data only after user wants to

Tags: c++, c++builder, lookup, vcl

I'm building a VCL c++ builder application.  I would like to see if anyone knows of a component that can load data in the lookup upon drop down only after a user has typed a few letters to limit the rows queried?  Preferably after pressing Tab, or Enter.

What I would like best is to get a behaviour similar to what Linux command line has, but that might be wishful thinking.  The way it would work is to drop down the combo list after user presses tab only if there is multiple options available, and to fill in additional text till the point where characters are not the same anymore, then if user presses tab again, drop down list.

The next best would be if the drop down would only allow drop down if user has typed a few letters, then pressing a specific button opens the dataset with the parameter of the typed text so far, then drops down the combo.

Does a component like this exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [TMS Software](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/). I'm not sure if it has something exactly for you, but their components are quite flexible. And you can send a feature request to them - to consider for next update. If you are lucky they might add it to next release.